# iReport propertie values not saved

Tags: properties, ireport

I am using jasper ireport 5.6 and after changing properties

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.cell.border
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.cell.background
```

from false to true, I cannot change them back. Values are always set to true.

Any ideas??

thank you

Comment: Where did you change it? Can you post the screenshot?

Comment: i change it in tools-->jasperreport properties tab